# Calculating DTFT

Tags: transform, dtft

When calculating DTFT of $\left( 1/2 \right)^{n} u \left[ n \right]$. We evaluate the sum as follows:
[image: DTFT]

Please correct statements and answer questions below:

1. So to go from STEP 1 to STEP 2, the limits of the series are changed from $-\infty$, $+\infty$ to 0, $+\infty$ because $u \left[ n \right]$ is $1$ for $n \geq 0$ and $0$ otherwise. Correct?
2. In STEP 2 we substitute the value of $x \left[ n \right]$ so the term $u \left[ n \right]$ is not found in STEP 2 because it is evaluated as $1$. Correct?
3. If term $u \left[ n \right]$ is no longer in STEP 2 equation how can we use the transform equation (indicated by arrow) in table when only $ \left( 1/2 \right)^{2}$ remains?

If you have a different explanation on how to transition from STEP 1 to STEP 3. Please feel free to comment.

---

My solution is below. I want to comment but I cannot attach images in comments.

[image: Solution_DTFT]

Comment: This is not homework since it is a solution from a book. I am practicing these questions. See My notes attached below.

Comment: $\displaystyle\left(\frac 12\right)^n e^{-j\omega n}= \left(\frac 12e^{-j\omega}\right)^n$ where $\displaystyle\left|\frac 12e^{-j\omega}\right| = \frac 12 < 1$ and so $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac 12\right)^n e^{-j\omega n} = \frac{1}{1-\frac 12e^{-j\omega}}$$

Comment: OK, thanks @DilipSarwate. This shows why the series formula was picked for the solution because of the magnitude of (1/2) being less than 1.  But could you please answer the 3 questions posted above. Especially question 3, as we are solving the problem using formula that doesn't have u[n] in it.

Comment: The value of $u[n]$ was included when in the transition from Step 1 to Step 2, the range of the summation was changed from all integers to all nonnegative integers. Since this bothers you, keep the range to all integers and put in $u[n]$ explicitly so that everything matches to the way you like to think.

Comment: what is the book you are referring to